# How to get the maximum number intersections on an interval tree after an update and get the interval where it happens?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a set of axis aligned rectangles and I need to find the maximum number of intersecting rectangles and the intersection where it happens (any or all of the intersections if there are multiple, either way it's fine).

You might notice this questions is very similar to these two questions https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18611/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-maximum-subset-of-intersecting-rectangles and [Max number of overlapping rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677168/max-number-of-overlapping-rectangles).

I'm following a similar approach to the top answers on those two questions. First I separate the rectangles into two segments, the bottom part where it begins (open interval), and the top part where it ends (end interval). And then sort those new segments based on their x value. Having done that I would create an interval tree and start going through the segments, if I encounter an open interval I would add it to the interval tree, and if I encounter an end interval I would remove it from the interval tree. And finally as the answers on those two questions say: **I would have to keep track of the maximum number of intersections after each update (This is the part I'm having trouble with)**

On those answers they say that keeping track of the maximum number of intersections after each update would take **O(1) time**.

The only way I can come up with a solution is having an array Intervals and an array A where each Intervals[i] is either the beginning or the end of an interval, and A[i] would have the count of how many rectangles are intersecting at Intervals[i]. So that when an interval is added or removed I could update A and Intervals using binary search and then update the values in A from the beginning of the new interval up until the end. But this would give me an **O(2 * log(n) + (interval_end - interval_beginning)) linear solution** (in the worst case where the interval being added or removed surrounds all other intervals).

Stating formally the problem: **How can I get the maximum number of intervals intersecting after an update in O(1) or O(log(n)) time?**

Here is the code for my solution in python. A function that takes in the open and ending segments and outputs the maximum number of intersecting intervals:

```py
import bisect

def max_intersections(segments):
    # Segments have format ((a, b), (c, d), 'b') for open segments
    # And ((a, b), (c, d), 'e') for ending segments
    max_count = 0
    intervals = []
    A = []
    segments = sorted(segments, key=lambda x: (x[0][0], x[2])) # Process open segments first

    for segment in segments:
        if segments[2] == 'b':
            # Open segment, insert interval

            index_beginning = bisect.bisect_left(intervals, segment[0][1])
            intervals.insert(index_beginning, segment[0][1])

            index_end = bisect.bisect_right(intervals, segment[1][1])
            intervals.insert(index_end, segment[1][1])

            # Add one to all elements in A[index_beginning:index_end + 1]
            for i in range(index_beginning, index_end + 1):
                A[i] += 1
                max_count = max(A[i], max_count) # Keep track of the maximum

        else:
            # End segment, remove interval

            index_beginning = bisect.bisect_left(intervals, segment[0][1])
            index_end = bisect.bisect_right(intervals, segment[1][1])

            # Subtract one to all elements in A[index_beginning:index_end + 1]
            # Before removing the elements

            for i in range(index_beginning, index_end + 1):
                A[i] -= 1
            intervals.pop(index_end)
            intervals.pop(index_beginning)

    return max_count
```

There might be some small mistakes on the code, but the general logic of the algorithm is there (Please go easy on me).

As you can see at each step I'm performing two binary searches and looping through all indexes between interval_beginning - interval_end. In the worst scenario, the interval would surround all other intervals, having to go through all positions in A, giving an O(N ^ 2) time. **What can I do to have the function max_intersections take O(N * log(N)) time?**